# Power BI Parent-Child Hierarchy Duplicated Rows

Tags: matrix, powerbi, dax, parent-child, hierarchy

I have a data WBS table (Work Breakdown Structure) that contains parent-child hierarchy and it's lined with another activity table by WBS id (link works just fine). WBS table as below:

[image]

by using parent-child IDs I created **Path, Path Length, Level 1, Level2, ...**

```
Path = PATH(
    TASK_WBS[wbs_id],
    TASK_WBS[parent_wbs_id])
```

---

```
Level 1 ID = PATHITEM(
    TASK_WBS[Path],
    1,
    INTEGER)
```

---

```
Level 1 = 
    VAR  NAME_X= CALCULATE(
        MAX(TASK_WBS[wbs_name]),
        FILTER(ALL(TASK_WBS),
        TASK_WBS[wbs_id]= EARLIER(TASK_WBS[Level 1 ID])
)
    )
    RETURN 
    if(NAME_X=BLANK(),
    TASK_WBS[wbs_name],
    NAME_X
    )
```

When I create Matrix table with assigning levels and task name (under levels);
[image]

As seen, repeating level names without any data underneath of it and it happens for all hierarchy levels. it's quite eye exhauster. the expected view is;

[image]

how to solve this issue ? Thanks in advance.